# how to use fengyuanchen cropper for multiple images

Tags: jquery-plugins, cropper

I'm creating the the image cropper by using fengyuanchen cropper library it is work as well but I want to use it for multiples images as the below screenshot But it'm simply difficult for me to reinitialize this [plugin](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper/tree/master/examples) because it support only one avata images.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CropperJs supports that feature. 
You can do it in javascript like this:

```
     <script>
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      var images = document.querySelectorAll('img');
      var length = images.length;
      var croppers = [];
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        croppers.push(new Cropper(images[i]));
      }
    });
  </script>
```

This code snippet could be found on the official Github repository 
https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs/blob/35c6ce5bc345317c1acfb39e1ceab8af6dee1247/examples/multiple-croppers.html